# 【Julia: DataFrame】 How to combine two lines into one using `|>`

Tags: julia, pipeline, dataframes.jl

Consider the following:

```
df = DataFrame(A=[-1,missing,1],B=[10,20,30])

3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ A        B
     │ Int64?   Int64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │      -1     10
   2 │ missing     20
   3 │       1     30

cond = df.A .> 0.                      #1
cond = replace(cond, missing => false) #2
df[cond,:]
```

Is it possible to combine `#1` and `#2` into one line using `|>` like

```
cond = df.A .> 0 |> replace(missing => false)
```

which fails.

Comment: "Pipes in Base are very limited, in the sense that support only functions with one argument and only a single function at a time"

Comment: `df[coalesce.(df.A .> 0, false),:]` achieves the same, using `coalesce` which is good for `missing` handling.

Comment: You can use `dropmissing` like: `subset(dropmissing(df, :A), :A => x -> x .> 0)` or `filter(:A => x -> x .> 0, dropmissing(df, :A))` to get the same. Or using `coalesce` as given in the comment from Dan Getz: `subset(df, :A => x -> coalesce.(x .> 0., false))` or `filter(:A => x -> coalesce.(x .> 0., false), df)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes in Base support only functions with one argument. When combining the pipe with an anonymous function it will work, where `(df.A .> 0)` needs to be in `(` and `)`

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A=[-1,missing,1],B=[10,20,30])

cond = (df.A .> 0) |> x -> replace(x, missing => false)
cond
#3-element Vector{Bool}:
# 0
# 0
# 1

# Or using coalesce.
cond = (df.A .> 0) |> x -> coalesce.(x, false)
```

Another possibility will be to use the package [`Pipe.jl`](https://juliapackages.com/p/pipe), where `@pipe` needs to be used and the placeholder is `_`.

```
using Pipe: @pipe
cond = @pipe (df.A .> 0) |> replace(_, missing => false)
```

Beside `Pipe.jl` this works also with [`Hose.jl`](https://juliapackages.com/p/hose)

```
using Hose
cond = @hose (df.A .> 0) |> replace(_, missing => false)

#or
cond = @hose (df.A .> 0) |> replace(missing => false)
```

or with [`Plumber.jl`](https://juliapackages.com/p/plumber)

```
using Plumber
cond = @pipe (df.A .> 0) |> replace(_, missing => false)

#or
@pipe cond = (df.A .> 0) |> replace(_, missing => false)
```

or with [`Chain.jl`](https://juliapackages.com/p/chain)

```
using Chain
cond = @chain df.A .> 0 replace(_, missing => false)

#or
cond = @chain df.A .> 0 replace(missing => false)
```

or with [`Lazy.jl`](https://juliapackages.com/p/lazy)

```
using Lazy
cond = @> df.A .> 0 replace(missing => false)

#or
cond = @as x df.A .> 0 replace(x, missing => false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just swap the order of them?

```
replace(df.A, missing => false) |> 
    x-> x.> 0

# or simply
replace(df.A, missing => false) .> 0
```

Update: with [`Chain.jl`](https://github.com/jkrumbiegel/Chain.jl):

```
using Chain

@chain df begin
    _.A .> 0
    replace(_, missing => false)
end
```

Comment: I get weird errors when trying to do similar things with base R or other piping packages. Unsure why